# Do I need a source compiled version of LLVM to create function/module passes?

Tags: macos, llvm

Right now, all I need to be able to do is create and add passes so that it can be ran on code and perform analysis on that. Will the llvm installed with homebrew work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write LLVM passes you would need LLVM headers to compile against and binaries (`llc`, `opt`, etc.) to load and run your compiled passes. I haven't used homebrew, but from what i can tell this is exactly what you need.

You can also compile LLVM right from its source, see [Build LLVM with CMake](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html).